# If it is hot, they like it a lot

Tags: riddle

They

> Have numbers and names but no address
>
> Have eyes but can't see
>
> Can land without wheels
>
> Can soar without wings

If it is hot, they like it a lot (but you like them not!)

Who are they?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Are they:

> Hurricanes?

They have:

> [Numbers](https://www.nhc.noaa.gov/aboutsshws.php) and [names](https://geology.com/hurricanes/hurricane-names.shtml) but do not remain fixed in one spot.

They have:

> [Eyes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eye_(cyclone)) but can't see (even though they're often over the sea).

They can:

> Land ([make landfall](https://www.enchantedlearning.com/subjects/weather/hurricane/landfall.shtml)) and they can obviously [soar](https://sciencing.com/long-hurricane-travel-over-land-12327531.html), despite having no wheels or wings (except, perhaps, the wings of the wind).

And they:

> Like it when they meet hot air, which is their [fuel](https://gpm.nasa.gov/education/articles/how-do-hurricanes-form), and cause destruction when so fuelled, which we do not enjoy.